# Why can't I add a web clip icon to my webapp in dashcode. I've tried everything?

Tags: javascript, html, ios-simulator, dashcode, apple-touch-icon

I've tried running this code from 2 different operating systems on a simulator, an iphone and an ipad and it won't show up.  The code is listed in the dashcode tutorial, but I can't get it to work.  Please help!

```
<link rel"apple-touch-icon" href="Images/WebClipIcon.png">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out web clip icons do not work properly unless there is a safari element in dashcode.  I was working solely with the mobile safari element.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just the equals sign is missing right after the `rel`?

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="Images/WebClipIcon.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for a start you need `rel="apple-touch-icon"`, not `rel"apple-touch-icon"`. And I would suggest using a path from the root of your server, for example "/Images/WebClipIcon.png". And make sure your image actually exists at the given path, i.e. if your site is `http://foo.bar`, can you definitely visit `http://foo.bar/Images/WebClipIcon.png` in a browser and see the icon?